# Objective-c block synchronizing data

Tags: objective-c

I'm developing a program that gets feed from Instagram. I'm really new to objective-c so please be patient with my question. I have a button that calls a method to get the feeds, but it is a block so when the method finishes sometimes the block still continues loading images. The problem occurs when I change the user. I clear the media array but the method fired fills the array with old user data. I tried to use a property userchanged but it seems that it cancels the current user data too. How should I synchronize these methods? I can't figure it out.

> @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *mediaArray;
>
> @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL currentUserChanged;

```
- (void)getInstagramSelfFeed
{        
    if (self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId != self.requestedPaginationInfo)
    {   
        self.requestedPaginationInfo = self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId;
        
        [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfFeedWithCount:15 maxId:self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId success:^(NSArray *media, InstagramPaginationInfo *paginationInfo){
            
            self.currentPaginationInfo = paginationInfo;
            
            if ([self checkIfCurrentUserChanged])
            {
                return;
            }
            
            [self.mediaArray addObjectsFromArray:media];
            
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"finishGettingSelfFeed" object:self];
            
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request Self Feed Failed %@", error);
        }];
    }
}

- (void)setCurrentUser:(User *)currentUser
{
    if (_currentUser != currentUser)
    {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
        
        [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] setAccessToken:self.currentUser.accessToken];
        
        [self.mediaArray removeAllObjects];
        
        if ([self.currentViewController isKindOfClass:[TimelineViewController class]])
        {
            self.currentUserChanged = YES;
        }
        MenuController *menuController = [MenuController sharedManager];
        
        [menuController updateAllViews];
    }
}

- (User *)currentUser
{
    return _currentUser;
}

- (BOOL)checkIfCurrentUserChanged
{
    if (self.currentUserChanged)
    {
        self.currentUserChanged = false;
        
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem. Now I'm sending the user that made the request and compare both.

```
- (void)getInstagramSelfFeed: (User *)user
{
    if (self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId != self.requestedPaginationInfo)
    {   
        self.requestedPaginationInfo = self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId;

        self.executingGetSelfFeed = true;

        [[InstagramEngine sharedEngine] getSelfFeedWithCount:15 maxId:self.currentPaginationInfo.nextMaxId success:^(NSArray *media, InstagramPaginationInfo *paginationInfo){

            self.currentPaginationInfo = paginationInfo;

            if (user != self.currentUser)
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"gettingSelfFeedCancelled" object:self];
                return;
            }

            [self.mediaArray addObjectsFromArray:media];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"finishGettingSelfFeed" object:self];

        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request Self Feed Failed %@", error);
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A big problem is that you have a mutable array, and it is a "copy" property. That's just wrong. When you access self.mediaArray, a copy of the instance variable is made, and then you modify  the copy. The instance variable itself is never modified.